# Testing devise user login but getting 401 unauthorized response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, minitest, rails-api

I'm using `devise_auth_token` gem in `rails-api` application where i'm trying to test if a `user` is `logged_in` then `user` is authorized to `render` through `index` action in `welcome_controller`.

**welcome_controller**

```
class Api::WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
    render json: {
      data: {
        message: "Welcome #{current_user.first_name}",
        user: current_user
      }
    }, status: 200
  end
end
```

**Routes**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth'
  namespace :api do
    get 'welcome', to: 'welcome#index'
    resources :socities
  end
end
```

**welcome_controller_test**

```
require 'test_helper'

class Api::WelcomeControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  def test_index_renders_message
    admin = users :admin
    sign_in admin
    get "/api/welcome"
    assert_response :success
  end
end
```

Fixture **users.yml**

```
admin:
  uid: admin@example.com
  provider: email
  email: admin@example.com
  first_name: Ahmad
  last_name: Hamza
  nickname: nil
  society_id: 1
  encrypted_password: $2a$10$kPXgGIFeHxoek/UgfwtVFeLCLYgIB82Cazj8c6GZz2I/p68ohfp9K #1234test
  confirmed_at: 2017-01-02 08:31:23
  confirmation_sent_at: 2017-01-02 08:30:59
  role: admin
```

**test_helper.rb**

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
  fixtures :all

  # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...
end

class ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers
end
```

**Error**

```
Failure:
Api::WelcomeControllerTest#test_index_renders_message [/Users/ahmadhamza/sites/manage_society/test/controllers/api/welcome_controller_test.rb:8]:
Expected response to be a <2XX: success>, but was a <401: Unauthorized>
```

How to check what is wrong going on?

Comment: I think you need to include the token in the `get` request. You need to do something like this: `get "/api/welcome?devise_token_auth=<INSERT TOKEN>", format: "json"`

Comment: I agree with @etagwerker, but maybe put the token in an auth header?